# How to show JTable data in a JasperReports

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jasper-reports

As a beginner, I usually use *JasperReports* to prepare reports from "database", but now in my project, I need to show JTable data in a *JasperReports*'s report and show the *JasperViewer* window by clicking a button.

can anyone help me please?

this is my jTable :|

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [JRTableModelDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRTableModelDataSource.html) implementation of [JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html) interface, which is designed to be used along with Swing [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) interface. Consider the following snippet:

```
TableModel model = new TableModelImp(); // TableModel implementation here
JTable table = new JTable(model);    
...
Map params = new HashMap();
...
JRDataSource dataSource = new JRTableModelDataSource(table.getModel());
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("pathToYourReport.jasper", params, dataSource);
JasperViewer.viewReport(print, true); // true == Exit on Close
```

See more in this [TableModel Data Source](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/#tablemodeldatasource) example.

See also:

- [JasperFillManager.fill(report, params, dataSource)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fill%28net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport,%20java.util.Map,%20net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource%29)
- [JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, isExitOnClose)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/view/JasperViewer.html#viewReport%28net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint,%20boolean%29)

Comment: But now I have another problem. in this program,the number of JTable columns will be determined by user. so when I'm designing the report using iReport-5.6.0, I don't know how may fields must be added.  (one field is needed for each column.)
any idea?

Comment: You are welcome :) Please see this great article by Jeff Ortman: [Building Dynamic Columns in JasperReports](http://solutiondesign.com/building-dynamic-columns-in-jasperreports/). The author doesn't create the report using iReport but in plain Java using JasperReport API.